# using GitLab account for logging in to other applications

Tags: php, gitlab

I am working on a project in my company and it is required that users login into my website using their gitLab accounts. what is the easiest way i can use to achieve that? i have been searching on internet for a few hours but i couldn't find a detailed tutorial. I am using php.

Comment: The standard your probably looking for is called: **OAuth2**. searching *that* should give you some good leads

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gitlab as [OAuth2 authentication service provider](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/integration/oauth_provider.html).

You can find more information on [OAath2 (RFC6749)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749).